# How to process data from one model field to another

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.2

I have models of `Exercise`, `Training` and `Workout`.

`Training` contains some exercises (`Exercise`)

`Workout` contains trainings (`Training`).

Snippet of my models.py:

```py
class Exercise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='exercises',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    details = models.ManyToManyField(ExerciseDetail, blank=True)
...


class Training(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='trainings',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, related_name='trainings',
                                       blank=True)
...


class Workout(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='workouts',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    trainings = models.ManyToManyField(Training, related_name='workouts',
                                       blank=True)
...
```

I would like to have possibility to use something like `Workout.objects.get(name='workout').exercises.objects.all()` to get a list/set of all exercises included in trainings of chosen Workout.

I would also like to have possibility to use ``` exercises`` field with Django Rest Framework to list all exercises, possibly with link to particular ```Exercise``` model serializer.

Can someone give a hint how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can query this with:

```
Exercise.objects.filter(
    trainings__workouts__name='workout'
)
```

With the consecutive underscores (`__`), you thus can look "through" relations.

This will thus return the `Exercise`s that belong to `Training`s that belong to `Workout`s with as name `'Workout'`.

Comment: I have edited my question, cause I know I can make query to get this information, but I also want to have possibility to have those exercises listed when I use DRF ```ModelSerializer``` on ```Workout``` model.

Comment: @jbb: this is covered in the [*serializer relations* section](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).